# MS Access: Count number linked records by individual and find lowest values

Tags: vba, ms-access, count

I have 2 tables,

`tblMain` with the details of each individual and 
`tblMedicalDx`, with details all illnesses for all individuals as a new row, linked to `tblMain` by [MainID]. `tblMedicalDx` has 3 checkbox fields for the type of illness [OM], [LRTI] and [BG] and a numeric field [BG val].

I need to do 2 things:

1. Count the number of each type of illness for each individual [OM], [LRTI], [BG] (this info will later be used to categorize individuals into groups).

   Any suggestion would be great. I am at the level of querying, but have avoided VBA so far, but realize that I will likely need to use VBA for this.
2. Find the lowest value for [BG val] for each individual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
[image]

For #1)

```
SELECT tblMain.person_name, Sum(Abs([OM])) AS CountOfOM, Sum(Abs([LRTI])) AS CountOfLRTI, Sum(Abs([BG])) AS CountOfBG 
    FROM tblMain LEFT JOIN tblMedicalDx ON tblMain.MainID = tblMedicalDx.mainID
    GROUP BY tblMain.person_name;
```

[image]

For #2)

```
SELECT tblMain.person_name, Min(tblMedicalDx.BGVal) AS MinOfBGVal
FROM tblMain LEFT JOIN tblMedicalDx ON tblMain.MainID = tblMedicalDx.mainID
GROUP BY tblMain.person_name;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you KacireeSoftware, that answered my question and worked perfectly! I guess I need to spend some time learning some syntax!

Comment: I have another question for you, I would like to include other variables from tblMain in these queries (eg. [IAR]). However, I can't seem to do that without getting multiple rows for each person.  Alternatively, I could append the minBGvalue to tblMain.

Comment: In order to maintain single rows per person, you must aggregate any fields which have a one-to-many relationship with the record in `tblMain` You can group by any field in `tblMain` in the examples I have given you without getting multiple rows. If, however, you want to display any fields from `tblMedicalDx` in your results, those fields would HAVE to be aggregated in some way (ie., `Sum([numberField])`; `FIrst([textField])`; `Max([numberField])`)